# Prompt tuning for Dolly-v2-7b model for Question and Answer giving gibberish output?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, huggingface-transformers, nlp-question-answering

I am following this page for `Prompt tuning for Dolly-v2-7b model for Question and Answer`: https://huggingface.co/docs/peft/task_guides/clm-prompt-tuning

Instead of doing the training in old `pytorch way`. I am doing the training using `Trainer api`. Also in this link
https://huggingface.co/stevhliu/bloomz-560m_PROMPT_TUNING_CAUSAL_LM/tree/main , I see 2 files `adapter_config.json` and `adapter_model.bin`.

But when I save the model using Trainer api I do not see any `config file`.  Also model size is bigger than what is shown in above link.

Is this correct way to **train**, **save** and **load** model for Prompt Tuning. ?

**The inference take lot of time to generate. and gives some gibberish output**

Here is my code:
The use-case is:

I have `Context` which has lot of paragraphs and then `Question` , the model has to `answer` the `Question` based on `Context` in a professional manner. Also can it classify the `Question` as **relevant** if answer is present in `Context` and **irrelevant** if `answer` is not in `Context`

The code that I have written is:

```
    task_type=TaskType.CAUSAL_LM,
    prompt_tuning_init=PromptTuningInit.TEXT,
    num_virtual_tokens=30,
    prompt_tuning_init_text="Answer the question as truthfully as possible using and only using the provided context and if the answer is not contained within the context/text, say Irrelevant",
    tokenizer_name_or_path="dolly-v2-7b"
)
```

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("dolly-v2-7b")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("dolly-v2-7b",load_in_8bit=True,device_map='auto') #,load_in_8bit=True
```

`model = get_peft_model(model, peft_config)`

```
train_data = [
    {
        "Context": "How to Link Credit Card to ICICI Bank Account Step 1: Login to ICICIBank.com using your existing internet banking credentials. Step 2: Go to the 'Service Request' section. Step 3: Visit the 'Customer Service' option. Step 4: Select the Link Accounts/ Policy option to link your credit card to the existing user ID.",
        "Question": "How to add card?",
        "Answer": "Relevant. To add your card you can follow these steps: Step 1: Login to ICICIBank.com using your existing internet banking credentials. Step 2: Go to the 'Service Request' section. Step 3: Visit the 'Customer Service' option. Step 4: Select the Link Accounts/ Policy option to link your credit card to the existing user ID."
    },
    {
        "Context": "The python programming language is used in many different fields including web development, data analysis, artificial intelligence and scientific computing. It is a high-level language that is easy to learn and has a large community of users who can provide support and advice. ",
        "Question": "What is Python used for?",
        "Answer": "Relevant. Python is used in many different fields including web development, data analysis, artificial intelligence and scientific computing."
    }
]
```

## Define a function to map examples to inputs and targets

```
def preprocess_function(examples):
    tokenized_examples = tokenizer(
        examples["Question"][0],
        examples["Context"][0],
        truncation=True,
        max_length=1024,
        padding="max_length"
    )
    tokenized_examples['labels']=tokenizer(
        examples["Answer"],
        truncation=True,
        max_length=1024,
        padding="max_length",
        return_tensors="pt")['input_ids'][0]
        
    return tokenized_examples
```

`tokenized_train_data = [preprocess_function(example) for example in train_data]`

```
class DemoDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        sample = self.data[idx]
        
        item = {k: torch.tensor(v) for k, v in sample.items()}
        return item
```

`dataset = DemoDataset(tokenized_train_data)`

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="results",
    learning_rate=1e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=1,
    num_train_epochs=10,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_steps=1,
    save_steps=1,
    logging_dir="logs"
)
```

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=dataset,
    # data_collator=data_collator,
    tokenizer=tokenizer
)
trainer.train()
```

**Is this correct way to save?**

`trainer.save_model("dolly3b_demo_model")`

**Inference**

**Is this correct way to do inference**

```
from peft import PeftModel, PeftConfig
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("dolly-v2-3b")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("dolly3b_demo_model")
model = get_peft_model(model, peft_config)
```

```
# Define example
context = "How to Link Credit Card to ICICI Bank Account Step 1: Login to ICICIBank.com using your existing internet banking credentials. Step 2: Go to the 'Service Request' section. Step 3: Visit the 'Customer Service' option. Step 4: Select the Link Accounts/ Policy option to link your credit card to the existing user ID."
question = "How to add card?"

# Encode inputs with prompt and tokenize
inputs = [f"{context} {question}"]
inputs_encoded = tokenizer(inputs, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=1024, return_tensors="pt")
```

```
outputs = model.generate(input_ids=inputs_encoded["input_ids"], attention_mask=inputs_encoded["attention_mask"], max_new_tokens=200,)
print(tokenizer.batch_decode(outputs.detach().cpu().numpy(), skip_special_tokens=True))
```